# How to display html format in text area

Tags: html, xhtml

I have created  but now when user add html formating in that text area with html codes like

```
<b>the codes are working </b>
```

they are showing up same as written, instead of "**the codes are working** "
so how do i enable that in simple HTML form.

Comment: Could you show us somebit of your code, there might be an error somewhere.

Comment: share you code ? myabe `<pre>` will help

Comment: You can retrieve textarea text with [`$.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)!

Comment: `<pre contenteditable="true"></pre>`???

Comment: In a comment you say you want to have `<TMPL_VAR file_descr>` inside `textarea`. That’s not HTML formatting. What is it and how does it relate to HTML formatting (which you surely cannot do inside `textarea`)?

Comment: Hello leave <tmpl_var file_descr> what i want is in <textarea> box if some one uses html tags, it shows same in output, i need them in rich text format.

Answer (score 0):

Textarea cannot display any html structure. You should use `<pre>` tag, but if you want to edit in the same time, use `contenteditable` attribute.

```
<pre contenteditable="true"><b>the codes are working</b></pre>
```

I think that you are trying some editor. You can use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/) also can be useful.

Comment: I dont want to edit text after, in html form it says 
    <TD><textarea name="file_descr" cols=48 rows=7 style="width:100%"><TMPL_VAR file_descr></textarea></TD> so where do i add <pre>?